# How do I adjust the box sizes that web parts go in on SharePoint sites?

Tags: 2007

I'm creating a site in a SharePoint 2007 environment and although the page looks great when viewed in 1920x1080, the page does not adjust at all for lower resolutions.

Is there a way to set the boxes on the left and right that the web parts are placed in so that they will auto adjust based on the resolution available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the default css class for webparts and add an `overflow-x:auto`.This way whenever the container the webpart is in is smaller than the webpart itself, the webpart will be in a scrollable area.

Comment: Doesn't that do the exact opposite of what I want? I want the container to shrink down for monitors with lower resolutions, not expand.

Comment: Your page width will stay the same, it'll be only the webpart that scroll. Otherwise, you're stuck with a Javascript solution, attaching to the window.resize event and then rescale your content

Answer (score 1):

If you are only worried about one page, you could edit the page in SharePoint Designer to add some CSS that fixes your web part zone widths.

Comment: In this case I am only worried about one page, may look at the master page if this works well. What should I use CSS wise to get this to work properly?

Comment: What type of web parts do you have in the zones? I double-checked and the zones on the default page are specified as 70% and 30%. Therefore, it may be the web parts themselves causing the wide view. Also, are you sure it is the web parts and not something like the navigation?

Comment: When I set the web parts to use a specific width in pixels, the box behind them that they reside in still stays the same width causing the screen to stretch.